# Is it possible in C++ to have a method in the superclass that when called by each subclass returns a shared_ptr to that subclass?

Tags: c++, subclass, superclass, virtual-functions

I want all children of a superclass to perform a similar action. So I figured I could have a method in the superclass to do so. The action requires sending a copy of (or shared_ptr to) itself as an argument to a method. But I do not know if such thing is possible or not, and if yes, how should it be done.

To clarify my question, please consider the following example. I want the printouts to be "Child" and "Parent". The current code prints out "Parent" and "Parent". Of course this is expected from this code as I am returning copying *this as a Parent type inside make_shared.

The question is if I could get the expected behavior. Please note that in the real case, there are many children, so implementing the function getPtr() in each is not that easy.

Thanks for your help.

```
class Parent
{
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Parent> getPtr() { return std::make_shared<Parent>(*this); } // I tried make_shared<decltype(*this)> also, but the code does not compile.

  virtual void printName() const { std::cout << "Parent\n"; }
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
  void printName() const override { std::cout << "Child\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Child1 c;
  auto cPtr = c.getPtr();
  cPtr->printName();       // I want this to print "Child", but it prints "Parent" (as expected)

  Parent p;
  auto pPtr = p.getPtr();
  pPtr->printName();
}
```

Comment: `virtual std::shared_ptr<Parent> getPtr() const { return std::make_shared<Parent>(*this); }` in the Parent class, and `std::shared_ptr<Parent> getPtr() const override { return std::make_shared<Child1>(*this); }` in the Child1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are doing, but you certainly want to derive your `Parent` from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

This will give you a member function `shared_from_this()` (which is more or less what you want to achieve via `getPtr()`).

However, it must be stressed that your `Parent` objects must themselves be managed by `std::shared_ptr`. I.e., this will work only and only if

```
std::shared_ptr<Parent> p = std::make_shared<Parent>();
```

Then you can use `p->shared_from_this()` to give you a shared pointer.

Comment: Important for me is actually to get shared_ptr<Child> or alternatively a shared_ptr<Parent> that can be cast to Child. Is it possible to do so with your proposed method?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do a `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to upcast your `Parent` pointer to `Child`.

Comment: I will also note that you can't have a portable `getPtr()` implementation without `std::enable_shared_from_this`, because `std::shared_ptr` contains both the pointer part and the control block part. Without enabling shared_ptr, you are trying to magick up the control block out of thin air.

Comment: In the OP's code as given, using `std::enable_shared_from_this` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Eljay I see that, but I imagine that his intention was to return a shared_ptr without copy constructing *this, which the comment seems to indicate.

Comment: @jvd • once making the class `std::enabled_shared_from_this`, then the object becomes self-aware of its own ownership, and should not be constructed as not shared_ptr (such as a local variable or as a new).  The private key idiom along with a static factory function to make the objects is warranted.

Comment: @Eljay, good point. This solution could very well be better in OP's case.